# NGINX Redirection domain does not work

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'd like to redirect one of my domain to another one. Both domains are configured on Digital Ocean where I set up the DNS to point to the IP adresse of the server

#### nginx

```
    server {
        server_name domain1.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 permanent;
    }


server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

        ......

    }
```

`nginx-t` runs fine.

#### Problems

The address www.domain2.com is working but www.domain1.com is not redirected. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared the cache of `Chrome` and `Safari` and it is fine.